Proof: If $f\in\mathscr{L}^{\infty}(X,\mathscr{A},\mu)$, then $\{x\in X:|f(x)|>\|f\|_{\infty}\}$ is locally $\mu$-null.
I am self-studying Measure Theory by Donald Cohn. When proving this statement:

If $f\in\mathscr{L}^{\infty}(X,\mathscr{A},\mu)$, then $\{x\in X:|f(x)|>\|f\|_{\infty}\}$ is locally $\mu$-null.

the book wrote:

If $\{M_n\}$ is a nonincreasing sequence of real numbers such that $\|f\|_{\infty}=\lim_{n\to\infty}M_n$ and such that for each $n$ the set $\{x\in X:|f(x)|>M_n\}$ is locally $\mu$-null, then the set $\{x\in X:|f(x)|>\|f\|_{\infty}\}$ is the union of the sets $\{x\in X:|f(x)|>M_n\}$ and so is locally $\mu$-null.

I can see that the union of a sequence of locally $\mu$-null sets is locally $\mu$-null. But my question is: How can we make sure that such a sequence $\mathbf{\{M_n\}}$ exists? Could someone please explain this for me? Thank you very much!

Some related definitions:

Definition$\quad$ A subset $B$ of $X$ is $\mu$-negligible (or $\mu$-null) if there is a subset $A$ of $X$ such that $A\in\mathscr{A}$, $B \subseteq A$, and $\mu(A)=0$.


Definition$\quad$ Let $\mathscr{L}^{\infty}(X,\mathscr{A},\mu,\mathbb{R})$ be the set of all bounded real-valued $\mathscr{A}$-measurable functions on $X$, and let $\mathscr{L}^{\infty}(X,\mathscr{A},\mu,\mathbb{C})$ be the set of all bounded complex-valued $\mathscr{A}$-measurable functions on $X$.
In discussions that are valid for both real- and complex-valued functions we will often use $\mathscr{L}^p(X,\mathscr{A},\mu)$ to represent either $\mathscr{L}^p(X,\mathscr{A},\mu,\mathbb{R})$ or $\mathscr{L}^p(X,\mathscr{A},\mu,\mathbb{C})$.


Definition$\quad$ A subset $N$ of $X$ is locally $\mu$-null if for each set $A$ that belongs to $\mathscr{A}$ and satisfies $\mu(A)<+\infty$ the set $A\bigcap N$ is $\mu$-null. A property of points of $X$ is said to hold \textit{locally almost everywhere} if the set of points at which it fails to hold is locally null.


Definition$\quad$ We can define $\|\cdot\|_p$ in the case where $p=+\infty$ by letting $\|f\|_{\infty}$ be the infimum of those nonnegative numbers $M$ such that $\{x\in X:|f(x)|>M\}$ is locally $\mu$-null.


An Update
Thanks for @kobe's answer! I would like to add one more thing for my own record: that the set $A$ is nonempty, where $A=\Big\{M\in\mathbb{R}_+: \{x\in X:|f(x)|>M\}\ \text{is locally $\mu$-null}\Big\}$. This is because of the fact that $f\in\mathscr{L}^{\infty}$, which means $f$ is bounded, which implies there is a real number $M$ such that $|f(x)|\leq M$ for all $x$, which means the set $\{x\in X:|f(x)|>M\}=\emptyset$ and thus is $\mu$-null and so is locally $\mu$-null.


How can we make sure that such a sequence $\mathbf{\{M_n\}}$ exists?

If $t$ is a real number and $A \subset \mathbb{R}$ such that $\inf A = t$, then there is a sequence $a_1 \ge a_2 \ge a_3 \ge \cdots$ such that $\lim a_n = t$. Indeed, we can find $a_1\in A$ with $0 \le a_1 - t < 1$, and having chosen $a_1,\ldots, a_n\in A$ such that $a_1 \ge a_2 \ge \cdots \ge a_n \ge t$, choose $a_{n+1}\in A$ such that $0 \le a_{n+1} - t \le \min\{\frac1n, a_n-t\}$. This generates a decreasing sequence in $A$ with limit $t$.
By definition $\|f\|_\infty = \inf A$, where $A$ consists of all positive $M$ for which $\{x \in X : |f(x)| > M\}$ is locally $\mu$-null. So there are positive numbers $M_1 \ge M_2 \ge M_3 \ge \cdots$ such that for every $n$, the set $\{x\in X: |f(x)| > M_n\}$ is locally $\mu$-null, and $\lim M_n = \|f\|_\infty$.
